# Sensitivity to settings vs statistical sensitivity

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models, modeling, sensitivity-specificity, sensitivity-analysis

I am confused between two different properties of a model. Both are called sensitivity. First, sensitivity is another word for true positive rate. Second, the output of a model changes in response to its settings. These changes, often presented on a tornado plot, are also called sensitivity. Is there a way to avoid confusion, for example, calling the second sensitivity something else?

Comment: The sensitivity to settings use is closer to the natural meaning of sensitivity.  But it will be hard to change either usage.

Comment: Thank you, I'll use the same term for both.